# Can't get scanner function working on Epson ET-4550

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

The printer function worked 'out of the box' via WiFi but I had a struggle getting the scanner to work, and ended up having to connect it via USB cable and use Simple Scan.  Recently, even that has stopped working.  On the Epson site they say to DL and install imagescan-bundle-ubuntu-14.04-1.1.13.x64.deb.  I installed it, but it complained it couldn't find libboost-filesystem1.54.0. So I installed libboost-all-dev, but the latest version seems to be 1.58.0, so when I rerun the imagescan install it is STILL complaining that it can't find 1.54.0 !

Does anyone know who maintains the code for imagescan, and is there a way to get a version of the code that uses the latest version of libboost, or is there any other way around this that will get my scanner working again?

Scanner software development must be very unsexy in Ubuntu circles, as all the interfaces look like Windows 386, and even when it's working, it seems quite buggy and temperamental. :)

Comment: Epson scanners do work. Did you add the scanner IP address to `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? In 16.04 it has `libboost-filesystem-1.58`.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Fedora...

Make sure that your printer is connected to your network, then

```
cd /etc/imagescan/
sudo -H gedit imagescan.conf
```

(use your favourite text editor)

change the following line...

```
;myscanner.udi    = networkscan:esci://192.168.xxx.xxx:1865
```

to...

```
myscanner.udi    = networkscan:esci://192.168.PRINTER'S.IP:1865
```

(remove semi-colon and enter your printer's IP address: 1865 is the default port)